# The Fourier transform of a non L1 positive function.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, mathematical-physics

I am trying to prove that if $\phi \in L_{1,loc} (\mathbb{R^d}), \phi(x)\geqslant 0$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\phi(x)dx=\infty$, then Fourier transform $\hat\phi$ is unlimited.

### My try

By contradiction. Suppose that $\hat\phi$ is an limited function. Than  $\lvert {\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\hat\phi(\xi)u(\xi)d\xi}\rvert\leqslant c{\lVert u\rVert}_{L_1}$

Because $\int_{\lvert x \rvert<R}\phi(x)dx\to\infty$, then $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\phi(x)u(\frac xR)dx\to\infty$, where
$u(x)= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } \lvert x \rvert<1\\
0 &\text{if } \lvert x \rvert>2
\end{cases}$

If we express the first expression through the second one, we will come to a contradiction.

I tried to use the theorems about changing the order of integration to express the first integral in terms of $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\phi(x)\hat u(x)dx$ but these theorems are not applicable in this problem.
Could you suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the definition of $\hat\phi(0)$?

Comment: this is the Fourier transform

Comment: I know. I ask you: what is the value at $0$ of the Fourier transform of $\phi$?

Comment: It seems that the integral diverges when substituting zero in the formula. It will be possible to obtain that the Fourier transform diverges at all points from this?

Comment: No, but it shows that it is unlimited. You are not to show that it is unlimited at every point, are you?

Comment: You are right, thank you!